# Prevent org-mode from swallowing file-local variables

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables

It is sometimes convenient to define file local variables with
comments such as the following, which *must* be at the end of a file.

```
# Local Variables:
# fill-column: 80
# End:
```

However, in org-mode buffers, this comments are considered to be
“inside” the very last headline. For instance, in the following
buffer, the comments will be hidden whenever subtrees `C` or `B` are
hidden.

```
* A
* B
** C

# Local Variables:
# fill-column: 80
# End:
```

I don’t really mind this hiding.
**The real problem is that the comments will get carried along whenever I move the `C` subtree somewhere else.**
For instance, if I call `org-refile` on `C`, or if I move it around
with `org-metaup` (and the likes), the comments are moved along with
the subtree, and then they obviously stop working.

Is there a way to tell `org-mode` to stop doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on a quick skim through the documentation on [Org Syntax](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html), I don't think there is a built-in way for doing this.

One possible workaround would be to add a top-level headline such as

```
* File-local variables
```

above the local variables section and tag it with `:noexport:`. Of course, the tag is only necessary if you are planning on exporting the parent document.

---

If you want to look into implementing a custom solution, looking at how `org-mode` uses the `org-list-empty-line-terminates-plain-lists` variable *might* be helpful. As the name suggests, when this variable is set to a non-`nil` value, a single empty line is enough to end a plain list, so it might be possible to get something similar working for subtrees.

Comment: I've been putting `* The End` (or `;;;* The End` or similar) at the end of my Outline mode buffers. Nice to know about `:noexport:` for Org mode.

Comment: `* COMMENT Local Variables` also works for me.

Comment: I'ld recommend using `COMMENT`, as suggested by @rvf0068. That way, the whole headline with it's contents is treated as a true comment.

Answer (score 9):

I keep a top level headline at the end of my Org files called `* Configuration`.

I ensure it is tagged `:NOEXPORT:ARCHIVE:`

With this it does not get exported (thanks to the `:noexport:` tag) and additionally the content does not get revealed when cycling globally (thanks to the `:ARCHIVE:` tag).

I also put the various Org relation configuration options (`#+TITLE:`, `#+AUTHOR`, `#+OPTIONS`, etc) under this headline so they do not take up visual space unless I want to edit them.

Answer (score 7):

I have averted this problem inadvertently as I always use some footnote in my documents. Doing `C-c C-x f` will insert a footnote and that will auto create `* Footnotes` section at the end of the buffer.

This is a special buffer and it is never exported as a section by org-mode. So you would never need to move this section around in the hierarchy.

Even if you don't use footnotes, it won't hurt to keep an empty `* Footnotes` section at the end as it would never export as a section.

Here is what I would do:

- Do `C-c C-x f`
- Give the footnote some text like "This is a dummy footnote.".
- Delete the auto created reference `[fn:1]` from the main area (not the Footnotes section).

*I suggested doing this as I am not sure if org-mode detects the presence of valid footnote descriptions in the Footnotes section to count it as a special section.*