# How to set the Ispell language via a file variable in Org-Mode?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables, ispell, flyspell

I put the following in the beginning of the Org file:

```
* :noexport:
Local Variables:
ispell-local-dictionary: "american"
End:
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
```

And I start flyspell via a hook:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

But Ispell always uses the default dictionary instead of the american.

I also tried Org's language tag, but it does not seem to have any effect on Flyspell.

```
#+LANGUAGE:  en
```

How to define the Ispell language in the Org file?

**Update**

When I set the variable from within a `:noexport:` taged heading the variable will not be set:

```
* :noexport:
-*- ispell-local-dictionary: "american" -*-
```

But when I set the variable before the `:noexport:` tag the variable gets set:

```
-*- ispell-local-dictionary: "american" -*-
* :noexport:
```

Is this the intended behavior? And if so, how can I change it?

Comment: I'd also like to see some automatic hook for this. For the time being, I work around it by having a key binding for switching flyspell languages and re-evaluating the buffer.

See the [comment "Change dictionaries" by Florian Diesch in the Emacs Wiki on Flyspell](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell).

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/prevent-org-mode-from-swallowing-file-local-variables)